# Maximum request length exceeded on service call in .Net

Tags: c#, request, max

I'm facing a problem with the JSON size I'm sending to my service:

> MAXIMUM REQUEST LENGTH EXCEEDED

I tried increasing the `maxRequestLength` value to `214748364`, but it still isn't working.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="214748364" 
             executionTimeout="100000" />
```

Any fix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded? Try changing byte size in `maxAllowedContentLength` too.

Comment: i set my maxAllowedContentLength to "1073741824".still it is not resolved

Comment: How big is the JSON you want to send?

Comment: 12367538 is the size of my request object which is less than maxRequestLength value I have set